# Hover Effect on Image/Text both (web)

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I'm trying to make the hover effect, where after hover the image dims and text will be bright. Although the image dimming works, the text opacity isn't changing. Can someone take a look? My website is https://www.hirooaoy.com/

Here's the code:

```
.image-overlay:after {
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}

.sqs-dynamic-text {opacity: 0.2;}

.image-overlay:hover:after{
    opacity: 1;
}

.image-overlay:hover:after .sqs-dynamic-text{
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: plz prefer this link easy to understand bro @Hiroo

http://css-workshop.com/hover-box-text-over-images-on-hover-and-more/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using opacity use alpha values
like foe 0.2 opacity use

```
rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
```

here first three parametrs are colors(red, green and blue) and fourth one is alpha